# how do you concatenate strings in ftHTML

Tags: fthtml

How do you concatenate strings with variables in ftHTML?

I'm used to doing something like this:

```
div {
  "Hello " + @myVar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ftHTML does not have an operator to combine strings and variables (*anymore*), all you need to do now is simply interpolate the variable with the `${}` syntax:

```
#vars
  myVar "World"
#end

div
{
  h1 "Hello ${ @myVar }" 
}
```

Will produce:

```html
<div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
```

If you would like to concatenate 2 strings in general, all you need to do is make them siblings to the same parent:

```
#vars
  myVar "World"
#end
div
{
  div { 
    "Hello ${ @myVar }! My name is " a (href=examplebio.com) "John" " Now goodbye ${ @myVar }!" 
  }
}
```

Will produce:

```html
<div>
    <div>Hello World! My name is <a href="examplebio.com">John</a> Now goodbye World!</div>
</div>
```

For more info, review the [documentation](https://fthtml.com/documentation/#language-string-interpolation)